# Usage of “in der Tat”

Tags: usage

I learned from a [dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/tat) that the phrase *in der Tat* means *indeed*.

Can I use this phrase as a positive response to a statement?

> A: Heute ist es so kalt!
>
> B: In der Tat!

Or can I only use it to modify a sentence?

> In der Tat stimmt, was du gesagt hast.

Comment: I would like to inform you that, while both sentences are correct, nobody uses *in der tat* unless in old books (and one particularly annoying TV commercial). So, should you use it, people might think you are joking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use it in both instances. The second one sounds a bit awkward, however. I’d suggest a small modification:

> In der Tat, es stimmt was du gesagt hast.

or

> In der Tat, was du gesagt hast stimmt.

or (suggested by Toscho):

> Es stimmt in der Tat, was du gesagt hast.

And indeed does *indeed* mean *in der Tat*, quite literally even, since *deed* and *Tat* [are cognates](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tat).

Comment: In both cases, `in der Tat` is prepositioned to the sentence. This reflects the English usage very well, but I'd call it bad style at least in written German. In written German, I'd say: `Es stimmt in der Tat, was du gesagt hast.`

Comment: There is nothing at all wrong with „In der Tat stimmt, was du gesagt hast.“  Another example: „In der Tat regnet es.“  Note the word order! Similarly „In der Tat stimmt das, was Du gesagt hast.“, and the „das“ can be omitted.

Comment: So it is correct to say both `In der Tat regnet es.` and `In der Tat, es regnet.`, right?

Comment: @MikaH.: yes. *Indeed* it is ;)

Comment: @MikaH. And so is "Es regnet in der Tat" and it works the same if you replace "In der Tat" with, e.g., "tatsächlich". -> "Tatsächlich regnet es." - "Tatsächlich, es regnet" - "Es regnet tatsächlich".